# Truffle Unbox Error while using truffle unbox react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, truffle, unbox

I am using truffle unbox react, but it is failing to set up:

> Preparing to download
>   √ Preparing to download
>   - Downloading
>   √ Downloading
>   - Cleaning up temporary files
>   √ Cleaning up temporary files
>   - Setting up box
>   × Setting up box
>   Error: Error: Error: Command failed: cd client && npm install
>   gyp ERR! configure error
>   gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
>   gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder. (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
>   gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
>   gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
>   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
>   gyp ERR! command "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
>   gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Javaid\Desktop\myDapp\client\node_modules\scrypt
>   gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
>   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
>   gyp ERR! not ok
>   npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
>   npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Javaid\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-05-04T19_24_38_096Z-debug.log
>
> at Object.unbox (C:\Users\Javaid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\truffle-box\box.js:69:1)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>   Truffle v5.0.15 (core: 5.0.15)
>   Node v10.15.3

Javaid@DESKTOP-6RRO05J MINGW64 ~/desktop/myDapp

Comment: Have you installed Python and added it to your PATH?

Comment: no. how do i do that?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Windows, but you can download it at https://www.python.org/downloads/

Comment: I'm getting the same. As far as I can see Python is added to my path correctly. Ive added to both user variables and systems variables like ..

PYTHON = C:\Users\tamnorris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32
In Path ... %PYTHON%\

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to replace the command with:

```
truffle unbox LibertyLocked/truffle-react-ts-template
```